# Serrated locking part

Tags: mechanical-engineering, mechanisms, fasteners

I need to fixate something at adjustable approximate angles. It doesn't need to have a lot of holding power. So the idea is to have washers/nuts that are serrated, that when closed in together, locks fixed. Then when loosened, can be readjusted. Like here:

[image]

Are there washer/nut parts with serrated locking mechanism as twice shown in this pic?

Comment: many camera support systems offer this.

Comment: If you drew that then have it 3d printed.

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to use [Nord-Lock](https://www.nord-lock.com/nord-lock/products/washers/) washers for your project. The holding power is quite strong, as it is based on the torque of the bolt/nut, not on the washer.

As you can see in the image from the web site, the surfaces of the washer are serrated in a manner similar to the detents in your image. The two parts are interlocked in such a way that rotation creates a force opposite to the fastening torque, effectively tightening the connection.

[image: nord-lock washer]

I've used this type of washer in a high vibration environment and found them to retain the fastening torque indefinitely. A bit more expensive than ordinary washers, but for your application, perhaps cheaper than a ground-up fabrication.